# How to populate a room database when migrating from version A to B

Tags: android, android-room

I have a room database version A and need to migrate to version B. The migration will create a new table with. The table must be prepopulated a definined by author of an app.

How to populate a new table with a given record when migrating from version A to version B of a room database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Migration`, insert the row using `insert()` or `execSQL()` on the `SupportSQLiteDatabase` handed to your `migrate()` function. Do this after having used `execSQL()` to create the new table.